# sql server 2014 group by date extract several fields

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mails (
  ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  Reference nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  Email nvarchar(70) NOT NULL,
  ETS datetime NULL, --Estimated Time of Shipping
  ATS datetime NULL, --Actual Time of Shipping
  ReadOn datetime NULL,
  Unsubscribed datetime NULL,
  Bounced datetime NULL,
  BouncedReason nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
  Active bit DEFAULT 1 NULL
)
```

I need to show info on a chart, and I need to group by Date.

therefore if I want to group details by ReadOn field for a certain campaign I build the following query

```
Select
    CAST(readOn as date) [date],
    COUNT(*) [read]
FROM Mails m
WHERE m.Reference=@Reference
GROUP BY  CAST(readOn as date)
ORDER BY CAST(readOn as date) ASC

and I get something like this:

sDate       read
NULL        360
2016-05-05  67
2016-05-06  123
2016-05-07  84
2016-05-08  62
2016-05-09  89
2016-05-10  17
2016-05-11  12
2016-05-12  8
2016-05-13  4
2016-05-14  4
```

But I would like to extract, in the same query, not only ReadOn field, but also other fields like ETS, ATS, Unsubscribed/Read & Unread and Bounced

and get something like this

```
sDate       read    ETS     ATS     Bounced     Unsub./Read Unsub/Unread
NULL        360     
2016-05-05  67      830     570     27          7               3
2016-05-06  123     0       260     4           9               5
2016-05-07  84      0       0       0           2               2
2016-05-08  62      0       0       0           2               4
2016-05-09  89      0       0       0           7               1
2016-05-10  17      0       0       0           5               6
2016-05-11  12      0       0       0           8               2
2016-05-12  8       0       0       0           1               3
2016-05-13  4       0       0       0           0               2
2016-05-14  4       0       0       0           0               2
```

Is there an easier way than building 6 different queries?

can at least indicate the path to follow?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Join to a generic dates table, SUM(Case when readDate = genericdate then 1 else 0) as read, SUM(Case when ETSdate = genericdate then 1 else 0 end) as ETS, etc

Comment: what does `dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, m.ReadOn))` ??

Comment: First, if you want to use dates as the grouping - and get counts of the fields that fall on that date, you need a table to store dates. 

Second, your question doesn't really make sense, because you are including Bounced, which doesn't relate to your base field (the date).  For example, how are you determining how many "bounced" records should be included in a date?  Is it the ones that are read on that date?  If so, you would need to include that logic for other fields, as well, meaning ETS would only be counted if it matched the read on date.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, using either a calendar date or distinct readon date as the base field and aggregating based on that, but it's not possible given the metrics you're trying to return.  If you can better explain what you're trying to accomplish (post your 6 queries), I can post an answer explaining how to consolidate them.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza
Actually, it is old fashion way for `CAST(readOn as date)`

Comment: @StanShaw  thank for your answer.. I think solution is using calendar date since neither `readOn` field nor any other will surely contain all the days from a certain date to today.
6 different queries are like the on I posted changing `readOn` with `Bounced`, `Unsubscribed`... To answer to your previous question: since "bounced" field will contain the date when mail has bounced (and same for other fields) I know how many "bounced" counting how many times is that date in `bounced` field.
More difficult to get Unsubscribed/Read and Unsubscribed/Unread since need to calculate 2 fields and not 1

Comment: @KyleHale Yes I think solution is in that field....will work on that, thanks

Comment: @Joe Actually, the table schema you provided has 'Bounced' as a bit, not as a date, so you will not be able to determine how many bounces you have on a specific date unless the schema you provided is incorrect.  Getting the Unsubscribed/Read or Unsubscribed/Unread is easy, but you need to determine how you want to evaluate it.  Are you asking for records that were read and unsubscribed on the same date - or are you asking for records that were unsubscribed on the date, but read at any point?  Again, it's unclear what you think your metrics represent.

Comment: @StanShaw Sorry, meanwhile changed Bounced field to date
About Unsubscribed/Read-Unread, no need to know which has both action in same date, but which has been read and unsubscribed and who has been unsubscribed without being read (i.e.; `where read =date and unsubscribed=date` is not OK, has to be `where read is not null and unsubscribed=date` for one field and `where read is null and unsubscribed =date)` for the other. But do not worry I hope to be able to refine the query: Just need help on the basic engine. I made a lot of test meanwhile but still not working as expected :-(

Comment: @Joe understood, but you can't group by a date if you're not relating them to a specific field - otherwise your metrics won't make any sense.  While your explanation makes sense, logically, it has no practical application.  The two should be on separate reports, honestly.  However, I will try to provide an answer tomorrow if I don't see anything in here.

Comment: @StanShaw Sorry Stan to waste your time, probably I'm not considering all aspects, or I'm not able to fully explain my needs, or probably both above reasons, but the answer of RichardCL seems working well, that's perhaps best explanation I could give you.  
Concerning your answer, I would it appreciate very much: will be a way to see 2 different approach, but only if it's ready already: I do not want you to waste more time on this issue.  
Thanks a lot again.  
Joe

Comment: @Joe I posted an answer.  Please let me know if it helps.  It should perform a lot better than using a CTE, Union Alls, and Pivots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with some pre-processing and a PIVOT. In this example, I've put the query into a stored procedure, so that it is contained and easy to test. I'm doing the pre-processing in a CTE, to keep the main query tidy.

First, create the table and populate it.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mails
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Reference nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    ETS datetime NULL, --Estimated Time of Shipping
    ATS datetime NULL, --Actual Time of Shipping
    ReadOn datetime NULL,
    Unsubscribed datetime NULL,
    Bounced bit DEFAULT 0 NULL,
    BouncedReason nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    Active bit DEFAULT 1 NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Mails (Reference, ETS, ATS, ReadOn, Unsubscribed, Bounced)
    VALUES
        (N'ABC', '2015-05-05', '2015-05-05', '2015-05-05', NULL, 0),
        (N'ABC', '2015-05-06', '2015-05-07', '2015-05-08', NULL, 0),
        (N'ABC', '2015-05-05', '2015-05-05', '2015-05-07', NULL, 0),
        (N'ABC', '2015-05-07', '2015-05-08', '2015-05-09', NULL, 0),
        (N'ABC', '2015-05-06', '2015-05-07', '2015-05-09', '2015-05-09', 0),
        (N'ABC', '2015-05-06', '2015-05-07', NULL, '2015-05-08', 0);
```

Then create a stored procedure with a parameter @Reference. I'm using a CTE to create a two column row set, with Date and Type as the columns. Then, in the main SELECT statement it's being pivoted to give the result you want.

The row set produced by the CTE looks like this.

[image]

Note: I haven't included the Bounced column, because I'm not clear what the requirement is for that; it's not a date column. However you should be able to extend this example quite easily.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.up_ReportMails
(
    @Reference nvarchar(20)
)
AS
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT CAST(ReadOn AS date) AS 'Date', 'R' AS 'Type'
        FROM dbo.Mails
        WHERE Reference = @Reference AND ReadOn IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(ETS AS date), 'E'
        FROM dbo.Mails
        WHERE Reference = @Reference AND ETS IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(ATS AS date), 'A'
        FROM dbo.Mails
        WHERE Reference = @Reference AND ATS IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(Unsubscribed AS date), 'U'
        FROM dbo.Mails
        WHERE Reference = @Reference AND UNSUBSCRIBED IS NOT NULL AND ReadOn IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(Unsubscribed AS date), 'V'
        FROM dbo.Mails
        WHERE Reference = @Reference AND UNSUBSCRIBED IS NOT NULL AND ReadOn IS NULL
)
SELECT [Date], [R] AS 'Read', [E] AS 'ETS', [A] AS 'ATS', [U] AS 'Unsub/Read', [V] As 'Unsub/Unread'
    FROM
        (SELECT [Date], [Type]
            FROM cte) AS C
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT([Type])
        FOR [Type] IN ([R], [E], [A], [U], [V])
    ) AS PivotTable
    ORDER BY [Date];
```

Then we can test it.

```
EXEC dbo.up_ReportMails @Reference=N'ABC';
```

[image]

Comment: Hi RichardCL, actually I was working on Pivot trying to extract dates but was not working well.
While your solution seems working well and solves also the problem of the Calendar Table: really very far from where I could ever have arrived. About Bounced, do not worry: I can modify the sproc, actually, have already adder 4 more fields.

Comment: Hi Again, would not abuse of your time and patience, but... assuming Mails table has also an "email" field and that field can be used to join Destinee Table, where among others field there is "countryID" field, how to  extract the above data splitted by country? I shall add the Country reference in each Select inside the CTE, joining the Destinee Table and extracting the countryID together the 'Type', or is there another (better) approach?

Comment: Hi @Joe I'm happy to try and help, but I don't understand your question. Can you post it as a new question, together with table structures and a limited amount of sample data, and saying clearly what you're trying to do, just like you did this one. Tag it as sql server and I'll see it.

Comment: Hi! @RichardCL do not worry, already tested and working. Just for your info, I used your routine and I joined the destinee table where I had CountryID field for each destinee, and got result splitted by country

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this code and it works.  Assuming you have a calendar table (if you don't have one, you can Google it and make one in about 10 minutes - they're very simple and will save you loads of time):

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '01/01/2016'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '05/06/2016'

SELECT  C.BaseDate,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN C.BaseDate = CAST(M.ETS AS DATE) THEN 1 END), 0) AS [ETS],
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN C.BaseDate = CAST(M.ATS AS DATE) THEN 1 END), 0) AS [ATS],
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN C.BaseDate = CAST(M.ReadOn AS DATE) THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Read On],
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN C.BaseDate = CAST(M.Unsubscribed AS DATE) THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Unsubscribed],
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN C.BaseDate = CAST(M.Bounced AS DATE) THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Bounced]
FROM Calendar C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mails M
    ON C.BaseDate = CAST(M.ETS AS DATE)
    OR C.BaseDate = CAST(M.ATS AS DATE)
    OR C.BaseDate = CAST(M.ReadOn AS DATE)
    OR C.BaseDate = CAST(M.Unsubscribed AS DATE)
    OR C.BaseDate = CAST(M.Bounced AS DATE)
WHERE C.BaseDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY C.BaseDate
```

Basically what you're doing is selecting every date from the calendar table within your date range, and then joining it to your mails table if ANY of the datetimes match that date.  The purpose of the left join is so that dates on which nothing occurs are still returned in your result set.  They will all be zeros, but it's better for consistency and in case someone wants to calculate averages from your report.

Once you have all the dates - and all of the records that have a matching datetime, you just need to count how many, for each date, have a matching ETS, how many have a matching ATS, so on and so forth.  Last, you group by the calendar date and you're all done.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer, but was trying to make a test on large table with real data, but was not so big, so I built a fake table with around 2M records, and solution with CTE takes on average 14" while yours takes more than 30". Therefore for this issue I will use @RichardCL solution, but your approach is interesting and will remember for future issues. Anyway thanks a lot for your time and patience. Joe

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the feedback and info - definitely good to know!  I'll upvote RichardCL's answer.